# Angular wont update UI on array ngModel change

Tags: arrays, angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I have a `<select>` that is two-way bound to `myArray` in `MyComponent`. I want to manipulate the content of `myArray` based on an asyc call to a `service`. When I push the new data into `myArray` the update will not be reflected in the select. If I instantiate the array with the data it will.

Why is that and how can I push instead of instantiate the array?

```
export class Foo {
    constructor(name: string) {}
}

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    myArray = [];        

    ngOnInit() {
        this.service.get().then((data) => {
           //This won't work: 
           this.myArray.push(this.doSomething(data));

           //This will work:
           this.myArray = [ this.doSomething(data) ];
        }
    } 

    doSomething(data: any): Foo {
        return new Foo("hello");
    }
}

<select multiple name="myArray" ngModel [(ngModel)]="myArray" >
    <option *ngFor="let a of ..." [ngValue]="...">...</option>  
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you said, Angular change detection works based on the reference to the array ignores the content.

A simple way to create a new array with an additional element is this:

```
this.myArray =  [...this.myArray, this.doSomething(data)];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the view is rendered before myArray is populated by the async service.

What happens if you put an *ngIf clause in the select element?

```
<select *ngIf=(myArray) multiple name="myArray" ngModel [(ngModel)]="myArray" >
    <option *ngFor="let a of ..." [ngValue]="...">...</option>  
</select>
```

You can also try creating a new function that updates myArray when the async service responds.  This may clue you in on the execution order.